# WIndows 10 MIDL.exe

Tags: c#, windows-10, midl

I need to convert some IDL files to C# class/Interfaces.

I am not able to get the MIDL.exe compiler.
I am running windows 10, and I have few Visual studio versions installed on my machine, I also download and install the [Microsoft SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8279) but I am not able to find the MIDL.exe binary any where.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86

or

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin

No clue where this binary is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a **Developer Command Prompt** and type `where midl`.

On my computer it's here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86

Install from here: [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

Comment: I do not have this path C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits {8.1 and NETFXSDK}

Comment: Where midl result -> INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

Comment: Install from here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk